# Get textext tags in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-textext

Hello Everyone i have this problem and really don't know how to solve it:
i'm using [Textext](http://textextjs.com/) tool to my website ,i type all my tags in the textarea but when i need the tags i can't get them here is my code:

> html code:

```
<textarea id="tagsa" rows="1" cols="70" style="color: black;"   placeholder="Add Your Article Tags.. Max=7" ></textarea>
```

> and here is my textext jquery code:

```
 function checkLength() {
            if ($("#tagsa").next().children().length < 7) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

$('#tagsa').textext({
    plugins: ' prompt  autocomplete ajax arrow clear  suggestions tags',
    prompt: 'Add one...',
    ajax: {
        url: '../data.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        cacheResults: true
    },
    tagsItems: eval(get_suggestion()),
    //eval(get_suggestion()),
    ext: {
        tags: {

            addTags: function (tags) {

                if (checkLength()) {
                    $.fn.textext.TextExtTags.prototype.addTags.apply(this, arguments);
                }

                else
                    alert("Only 7 Tags Allowed");

            }
        }
    }
}).bind('tagClick', function (e, tag, value, callback) {
    var url = "Finder.aspx?tag=" + value;
    window.location = url;
}).bind('isTagAllowed', function (e, data) {
    var formData = $(e.target).textext()[0].tags()._formData,
        list = eval(formData);

    // duplicate checking
    if (formData.length && list.indexOf(data.tag) >= 0) {

        data.result = false;
    }
});
```

**i tried this:**

```
  alert(document.getElementById("tagsa").value)
```

but it doesn't show me the inner text/tags

can any one help me with this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question/problem. Is your alert not working even though there is text in your textarea?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please add more details and clarify, and we'd be happy to help you out. The more code you isolate, the better -- we're much more likely to help with short, isolated code snippets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find this operation in the plugin's docs, but after diving in the code I found a way.

```js
$('#textarea').textext({
  plugins: 'tags',
  tagsItems: [ 
    'PHP', 'Closure', 'Java' 
  ]
});

$('#btn').click(function(){
  var tags = $('#textarea').textext()[0].tags()._formData;
  
  $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(tags));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-textext/1.3.0/jquery.textext.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="textarea"></textarea><br />
<button id="btn">Show Tags</button>
<hr />
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

http://jsbin.com/joquga

Comment: Wow You are a genius Thanks

Comment: @MohemmadAlBughdadi Thanks for you words ;). My pleasure. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are referring to the right element ? I just tried your example in my local machine and I am getting all the inner tags just fine.

Comment: my Question Just answer THX